# Can you Echo an if command? Is there a workaround if not? Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, echo

So I have the following batch code:

```
:AddMember
cls 
title Add Member
color 0A
set /p membername=Member name?
echo %membername% >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\members.txt
set /p memberpass=Member Password?
echo %memberpass% >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\memberspass.txt
echo :%membername% >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo cls >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo title >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo color 0a >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo echo Member: %membername% >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo echo Password: %memberpass% >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo set /p Memberoptions=What Would you like to do?     >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo echo 1. Nothing >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo echo 2. Change Password >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo echo 3. Change Username >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo echo 4. DELETE User >>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
echo if "%memberoptions%"=="1" goto :Enter
echo if "%memberoptions%"=="2" goto
```

In the last two lines I'm trying to get the program to write the if command into another block of code, is this possible? If not is there a workaround i just havent thought of?

Comment: what do you mean write the if command into another block of code? please describe your ultimate goal here.

Comment: Im trying to write the IF commands into the batch file "database.bat" when i say block i mean each :"_" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're goal is to write these two `IF` commands into `database.bat` as well. For that to work you need to escape the percent signs by doubling them:

```
echo if "%%memberoptions%%"=="1" goto :Enter
echo if "%%memberoptions%%"=="2" goto
```

Output:

```
if "%memberoptions%"=="1" goto :Enter
if "%memberoptions%"=="2" goto
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that!

Answer (score 3):

A far easier construction is

```
(
echo cls
echo title
echo color 0a 
)>>C:\Users\187242\Desktop\swag\database.bat
```

Where the parentheses ensure the `echo`s are redirected to the file. I've used `>` to create a new file. `>>` would append to any existing file (or create a new file if none currently exists)

The trick is to double **every** `%` that needs to be `echo`ed to the destination file. This is because in batch, `%` is the `escape character` for `%`. An `escape character` is used to temporarily turn on or off the special meaning of the character that is `escaped`. In its early application an <kbd>Esc</kbd> was sent to a printer before a sequence of otherwise-printable characters to control underlining, bolding, italicising and other features of a printer.

There are other characters which require an `escape` in batch, especially `>` `<` `|` and `)`. These require `caret` (`^`) as an escape. `%` is the exception that required `%` as an escape.